# Emails not being sent with PHPMailer 6

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm upgrading to phpmailer 6 and testing my forms.

If I use the following code, it doesn't work:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Sender = 'example@mydomain.com';
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], false);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

$mail->addAddress($to);
```

I have tried various combinations with setFrom (e.g. removing the boolean flag, omitting the $mail->Sender piece, omitting the addReplyTo) and it never works when using setFrom().

However, if I use this code, it does appear to work:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
$mail->addAddress($to);
```

Any idea why the setFrom() doesn't send the email?

Comment: How are you determining the email is not sent and not just blocked by the receiver?

Comment: Not receiving an email does not constitute proof that the email wasn't sent.

Comment: do you have any Exceptions?

Comment: If you use SMTP to send then also add `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

You have not said what you mean by "doesn't work". Does it throw errors, not send at all, or what? It would help to see an SMTP transcript (set `SMTPDebug = 2`).

Problems aside, this is a bad idea:

```
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], false);
```

This is forgery, and will cause your messages to be rejected or spam-filtered because it will break DMARC alignment. Setting `$mail->Sender = 'example@mydomain.com';` will help a bit as your envelope sender will be ok, but generally speaking don't do this as it's not going to help with deliverability.

One difference that `setFrom()` has over setting the `From` property directly is that it verifies the address immediately, and you can see the result - try this:

```
if (!$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], false)) {
    die('bad address');
}
```

If you give it a bad address, then sending will fail, whereas it may still be attempted if you have set the property directly - this may explain the difference you're seeing.

I would advise you to set it up this way, that is not forging either the from address or the envelope sender, but still making replies to form submissions go to the submitter:

```
setFrom('example@mydomain.com');
if (!$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
    die('bad address');
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it was still not working.  The emails are being bounced according to our logs, although I'm not always getting the bounced emails.  I think it may be settings on our IT department's end so I'm going to check with them.  Just wanted to make sure it's not an obvious problem with my script.

Comment: Please show the logs. It may give some information about why the message bounced.

Comment: I confirmed it is due to some settings on our IT end, not my code.  Thanks for your help though.  It was still informative.